# PA+PB+PC in triangle

Tags: geometry

For which point (P) of the plane of a triangle (ABC) the sum of distances PA+PB+PC is minimal?

I think it should be either the orthocentre or the centroid.

Comment: Nope, it is called the [Fermat point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point). When some angles of the triangle is $\ge 120^\circ$, the Fermat point is located at the vertex with obtuse angle. When all angles $< 120^\circ$, the Fermat point lies inside the triangle with $\angle APB = \angle BPC = \angle CPA = 120^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the orthocentre or the centroid. The point is called Fermat point.

If you draw an equilateral triangle (pointing outward) on each side of the triangle, connect the new vertex of each equilateral triangle to the opposite vertex of the original triangle, you will find that the three lines intersects at the same point. This point is the Fermat point.

To show that this point has the minimum sum of distances to $A$, $B$, and $C$, you can follow the solution 3 in [this page](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/fermat_point.shtml).